# Picking up radio station when connecting monitor on latop

Tags: 12.04

I have a laptop Asus G73JW ROG-A3B7M
Intel Core i7 || 16GB RAM || 802.11n+BT || 2 x 500GB Hybrid Drives || Nvidia GTX 460M

and I am picking up some staticy radio station when connecting my monitor over RGB connector.

My radio system is connected via my laptops headphone jack.  If I disconnect my extra monitor the radio station static disappears.

I am not sure what this is related to or even how to debug such an issue.  Any help is appreciated.

The monitor is a Acer P216HL and the stero is a TeAC nxt

Comment: As this is almost certainly a hardware problem and not related to Ubuntu, I recommend posting about this elsewhere such as [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Tom's Hardware Forum](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/). (Unless this is happening when you run Ubuntu but not when you run some other operating system such as Windows. That would be very weird...and definitely worth exploring here.)

Comment: Since it happens when you connect and disconnect a cable I suspect that this is a hardware issue. There are devices called chokes that you can put your monitor cables through that might help. A local amateur radio operator may also be able to help you out. Picking up radio stations over cables is certainly not unheard of, particularly for AM stations. This is probably off-topic here.

Comment: yeah your right... sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if I agree that this is OFF TOPIC, for your case I suggest you grounding.

A good cable for grounding your system may lessen the interference/static but having your connections "in phase" will also do the trick. This can be caused if you are getting the POWER from different regulators/no-break systems or from different power sources.

If the problem persist after grounding then you must consider using ferrite donuts at the end of the cables, previous to the connectors/plugs. The ferrite donuts will decrease considerably your interference/static and even RF.

**Sources:** *My current installation at a TV/Radio Station where I work.*

You should also consider moving this question to another forum and drop back a link in order to continue the support, if needed.

Good luck.